# TypeError: '__ensemble__' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, classification, typeerror

I don't know why it's not calling any ensemble. Maybe some parameter mess-up?

Forest Cover Type Data:
X = shape of (581012, 54)
y = shape of (581012, )

```
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn import model_selection

classifier_names = ["logistic regression", "linear SVM", "nearest centroids", "decision tree"]
classifiers = [LogisticRegression, LinearSVC, NearestCentroid, DecisionTreeClassifier]

ensemble1 = VotingClassifier(classifiers)
ensemble2 = BaggingClassifier(classifiers)
ensemble3 = AdaBoostClassifier(classifiers)
ensembles = [ensemble1, ensemble2, ensemble3]
seed = 7  

for ensemble in ensembles:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
    for classifier in classifiers:
        model = ensemble(base_estimator=classifier, random_state=seed)
        results = model_selection.cross_val_score(ensemble, X, Y, cv=kfold)
        print(results.mean())
```

I expect the ensembles to run for the classifiers, but the first ensemble didn't run. I changed order to `BaggingClassifier` first but that showed same error that not callable.

Answer (score 0):

For `VotingClassifier`, the estimators should be a list of tuples with names and model. 
Note you have create a model class and then give inside the tuple.

From [Documentation:](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html)

> **estimators** : list of (string, estimator) tuples Invoking the fit
>   method on the VotingClassifier will fit clones of those original
>   estimators that will be stored in the class attribute
>   self.estimators_. An estimator can be set to None using set_params.

For other two ensemble, you can problem only one base estimator and n number of estimators for the same base model. Loop through different classifiers, as you did your code but you have redefine the ensemble model every time.

> **base_estimator** : object or None, optional (default=None) The base
>   estimator to fit on random subsets of the dataset. If None, then the
>   base estimator is a decision tree.
>
> **n_estimators** : int, optional (default=10) The number of base
>   estimators in the ensemble.

Try this!

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data[:, 1:3], iris.target

classifier_names = ["logistic regression","linear SVM","nearest centroids", "decision tree"]
classifiers = [LogisticRegression(), LinearSVC(), NearestCentroid(), DecisionTreeClassifier()]


ensemble1 = VotingClassifier([(n,c) for n,c in zip(classifier_names,classifiers)])
ensemble2 = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator= DecisionTreeClassifier() , n_estimators= 10)
ensemble3 = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator= DecisionTreeClassifier() , n_estimators= 10)
ensembles = [ensemble1,ensemble2,ensemble3]
seed = 7  

for ensemble in ensembles:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
    results = model_selection.cross_val_score(ensemble, X, y, cv=kfold)
    print(results.mean())
```

Comment: Yours worked great. I need to try to assemble the classifiers and ensembles (also added RandomForest)...

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a meta ensemble on top of ensembles. Hope your `'__ensemble__' object is not callable` issue is solved. Kindly accept the solution and start a new one with more details about your meta ensemble model.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, AdaBoostClassifier, BaggingClassifier, VotingClassifier
from sklearn import model_selection
import warnings 
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") 

seed = 7 
classifier_names = ["logistic regression","linear SVM","nearest centroids", "decision tree"]
classifiers = [LogisticRegression, LinearSVC, NearestCentroid, DecisionTreeClassifier]
for classifier in classifiers:
    ensemble1 = RandomForestClassifier(estimator=classifier(), n_estimators= 20, random_state=seed)
    ensemble2 = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=classifier(), 
                                   n_estimators= 5, learning_rate=1, random_state=seed)
    ensemble3 = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=classifier(), 
                                  max_samples=0.5, n_estimators=20, random_state=seed)
    ensemble4 = VotingClassifier([(n,c) for n,c in zip(classifier_namess, classifiers)], voting="soft")
    ensembles = [ensemble1, ensemble2, ensemble3, ensemble4]

for ensemble in ensembles:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
    results = model_selection.cross_val_score(ensemble, X[1:100], y[1:100], cv=kfold)
    print("The mean accuracy of {}:".format(results.mean()))
```

Comment: `ensembles = [ensemble1, ensemble2, ensemble3, ensemble4]`. This wil get over written on every iteration of the loop

Comment: well-noticed. I can't get the ensemble in that classified for loop so I just did them individually. The RFC is also not taking a classifier.

Comment: RFC's estimator is decision tree, hence it cannot take any estimator as input. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html